# Provide an encrypted connection to a website without ssl certificate

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl, https

We want to implement https to our website. But given that our team have no experience with https/ssl things, it will take us a bit time to learn how to use encrypted connection on our website.

We want to make our website the more secure as possible during the time we try to implement an SSL certificate.

**So, we heard about a temporary solution we could use. Something like to ask the user (With a popup confirmation) each time he goes our website if he want to use a secure connection (Like a new certificate for each connection to our website)**.

I don't know anything about this "method", I don't even know what to search on google.

Is this even possible ? If yes, how you call this ?

Comment: Implementing SSL is pretty simple, no need for this temporary solution.

Comment: I think what you are referring to is a self signed SSL certificate. Implementing it is identical to any other certificate, the only advantage is that you don't have to pay for a certificate signed by a CA, you can just create one in for example IIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably refer to self-signed certificates as the temporary solution.
To implement them you already have to implement https at your server and the only difference to "real" https is that you don't buy a certificate from an established CA, but that you create your own. In this case the browser will not trust the certificate by default and need to ask the user to trust the certificate. Of course, not all users will simply trust some stranger so expect to loose more users of your site this way than you would loose if you don't use https at all.

Comment: Thank you Sir ! It helped me a lot to get started :)